# Extra mana for no apparent reason

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I just closed Dungeon Defenders last night with about 8m mana in the bank; I'd had it open, mostly idle, for a few days. I opened it up today and had 28 million. Does anyone have any idea how that could happen?

Comment: Happened to me too.  I had the max amount of mana - 150mil - and when the cap was raised by 20mil to 170mil, my mana went up by 20mil also.  Perhaps it was intentional, but I doubt Trendynet just decided to *give everyone 20 million mana*.  More likely it was a mistake.

Answer (score 7):

[But they did give everyone 20 million mana for Christmas](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?36913-Patch-7.15a-added-20-million-mana-into-my-forge&s=873505b01aaa9f249f3c0ca38afa9630).

Comment: I never got that mana bonus :(  I guess its because I didn't log in on that day.

Comment: They were in the present boxes underneath the Christmas tree in your Tavern, and they only opened after you completed the full campaign (similar to the secret room).

Comment: Note: Completing the full campaign *does* include Glitterhelm Caverns for the purpose of receiving the presents. We ran a couple of our friends through, and they couldn't open the presents until they'd completed GC.

Comment: Like OP, I had 20 million extra upon logging in, before I opened the Christmas presents.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have shop items by any chance?  When you are idle in game and you have items in your shop, people can join your game and buy it and you will get the mana.